# Is there a word that functions the same as "is facilitated by" in a cleaner way?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that functions the same as “is facilitated by” in a cleaner way?

My writing currently contains the following question: “Do reading and writing require contrasting skill sets?”

What I am trying to state in a simple way is “does a skill set that supports writing make reading more difficult because the skills that facilitate writing directly contrast with the skills that facilitate reading?”

I think “require” is not appropriate because it is too strong. Really, reading is facilitated by a particular skill set, it does not require that specific skill set.

However “Are reading and writing facilitated by contrasting skill sets” feels clunky.

Here are some word replacements I’m considering:

- Do reading and writing **draw on** contrasting skill sets?
- Do reading and writing **leverage** contrasting skill sets?
- Are reading and writing **compatible with** contrasting skill sets?

Comment: "Do reading and writing use the same skill sets?"

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're asking.  It doesn't seem simple, like "Do they use different sets of skills?" but rather something like, "Will you read better and write better if the one activity requires a different set of skills than the other does?"  So, please draw on whatever set of skills is needed to ask a clear question.  ;)

Comment: @TRomano I am actually considering the phrase "draw on"! I will edit the question to try and make things more clear.

Comment: Reading and writing are complementary skill sets. Like a mirror image. Maybe this is what you are trying to say?

Comment: What do you actually *mean* ?  Is this about neuro-physiology, and you mean "the two things use different parts of the brain".  Or so you mean "to learn, become expert, at the two things, requires different skills"  Or ??????

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***Are reading and writing informed by different skill sets?***

This employs OED sense 8b of the verb ***inform***:

> 8b. Of a quality, principle, etc.: to be the determinant principle of;
>   to give a thing its essential quality or character; to inspire,
>   animate; to pervade. In later use more generally: (of an experience,
>   etc.) to influence, to affect.
>
> ▸ a1398   J. Trevisa tr. Bartholomaeus Anglicus De Proprietatibus
>   Rerum (BL Add.) f. 27   Þis spirit animalis..passiþ in þe middel den
>   þat hatte logica to make þe intellect and vndirstondinge parfite. And
>   whanne he haþ informed þe intellect, þanne he passiþ to þe denne of
>   mynde.
>
> ?a1475  (▸?a1425)    tr. R. Higden Polychron. (Harl. 2261) (1865) I.
>   33 (MED)   Cristen men..when feithe and grace of sacramentes informede
>   the life of theyme.
>
> ?1555   T. Paynell tr. J. L. Vives Office of Husband sig. Qiiij   The
>   good example of ye husband, the which to informe and fashion the
>   womans life, and his family withall, is of no lesse valure and force,
>   then the example of a prince to informe the publique maners & customes
>   of a citye.
>
> 1605   G. Chapman Al Fooles i. i   Without loue..All vertues borne in
>   men lye buried, For loue informes them as the Sunne dothe colours.
>
> 1667   Milton Paradise Lost iii. 593   Not all parts like, but all
>   alike informd Which [read With] radiant light, as glowing Iron with
>   fire.     1700   S. Cobb Poetae Britannici 12   Unstol'n Promethean
>   Fire informs his Song.
>
> 1771   Muse in Miniature 144   This scull might once contain Some rich
>   materials for the lofty strain, Enform'd, enrapt with more than mortal
>   fire.
>
> 1814   H. F. Cary tr. Dante Vision III. vii. 132   The elements..and
>   what of them is made, Are by created virtue inform'd.
>
> 1820   Shelley Prometheus Unbound i. i. 31   Speak the words which I
>   would hear, Although no thought inform thine empty voice.
>
> 1871   M. B. Betham-Edwards Sylvestres II. ii. 38   Even in..happy
>   England the spirit of caste informs the very breath and life of the
>   nation.
>
> 1912   H. Belloc This & That 222   Just as an Englishman is English or
>   as a poem is informed by a definite scheme of rhythm.
>
> 1942   E. K. Chambers Sheaf of Stud. 100   There can be no doubt that
>   an early familiarity..with great books is one of the forces which make
>   most strongly for education. Insensibly, by ways silent and undreamt
>   of, it informs the character and moulds the imagination.
>
> 1996   Observer Life 31 Mar. 24/1   The belief that the British
>   working class is in terminal decline is often informed by a particular
>   idea about what working classness is.
>
> 2001   Amer. Hist. Rev. 106 1512/2   We see little of how his early
>   experience informed his worldview or affected his inner life.

Comment: I am hesitant to drop "contrasting" because I think it adds valuable information (what helps for one task might hurt for the other). But I also agonized over "different" vs "contrasting" vs "opposing" for a WHILE, so please tell me if I'm just overly committed to that word.

Comment: On "informed by" vs "facilitated by": I think these means two different things. Where informed by refers to influence, facilitated by refers to ease.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you're laying the groundwork for the old observation, "Don't confuse a love of reading with a gift for writing."

You can simply state that "reading and writing *involve* disparate [rather than contrasting] skills."

To address your longer statement, the gifts of creation and synthesis that *enable* one to be a writer don't hinder one from reading; on the other hand, the skills of comprehension and analysis that are required to effectively explicate a text aren't required to be able to enjoy reading it.

(Which I suppose is a long-winded way of saying that I'm not sure that I support your premise...)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the contrast you are making with reading vs. writing, you wish to ask whether their corresponding skill sets "**synergize**" or "**antagonize**" each other.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/synergy

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/antagonize

Answer (score 0):

“Draw on” and “leverage” both sound simpler. But not necessarily clearer. “Facilitated by” implies these skills make the activity easier. The other two simply say these skill are used when the activity occurs.

... but if I can take an uneducated stab at answering this interesting question within your question that you have asked in several ways ... no.

I would posit that the skill set for reading is quite possibly a sub set of that needed for writing ... mostly. Or at least the skill set for reading in no way hinders the writing process, and may indeed facilitate it. While you may be able to “write” a novel or poem in a general sense by way of using a stenographer or speech to text software, you would not have any real advantage over someone who is actually literate. If you define “writing” as that literal action of using a tool - pen, keyboard etc - to transcribe thoughts and ideas to written form, then I would think you would need every skill necessary to reading. The reverse may not be true (children most often learn to read before they write) but is complete literacy really only achieved when this activity can be performed in both directions, thoughts to words and back again from words to thoughts?

As an aside, it’s interesting that we usually learn the second half of the communication process involved in literacy (reading comprehension) before the first half of this process (writing).